# Bootstrap image height not responsive for mobile

Tags: css, image, mobile, bootstrap-4, height

Making a website with an image starting at top below nav-bar, I'm using Bootstrap 4 and css. For large screen I used background-image to make sure the image stretch full width of the screen. And for mobile version I used

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row leftmargin-row"
    <img src="images/1920 x 580 2.jpg" alt="child-pic" 
            class="img-responsive img-fluid">
</div>
```

Comment: please explain, in your question, exactly what you *do* see on the mobile device. (screenshots/diagrams always helpful too)

Comment: In mobile the image width settle within screen, but the height stretches too long. I used height: 100%, but no use, And sorry for the missing question above, using stack overflow for the first time not sure what happened to my remaining question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row leftmargin-row">
      <img src="images/1920 x 580 2.jpg" alt="child-pic" 
        class="img-responsive img-fluid">
   </div>
</div>
```

I think u forgot closing angle bracket after div...

Comment: i think you forgot to close img tag